# Maven - Jenkins issue

Tags: maven, jenkins

There are couple of issues I am facing in Jenkins integration . I run the scripts from local Eclipse and it works perfectly fine with Selenium Grid. I am trying to setup this whole thing in Jenkins and facing the following issues 
1. cannot find symbol - Seeing this issue in Jenkins and searched about this in Stack Overflow . Verified the JDK version and my pom.xml version matches with the one installed in Jenkins. 
2.I have three packages- One has the framework , second one has the main method and the third one has the code related to the application i am testing. I am converting my framework to a jar and uploading the entire thing to GIT . When i build the project jar using Maven install , its not including the framework jar which is causing the issue . I tried a lot of things suggested in Stack Overflow and it did not work. I am quite new to this kind of Maven stuff
3. I am not even able to run the scripts with the help of the runnable jar in my local because of issue# 2
Some of these have already been posted but i tried out those things and did not work for me or I might be missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maven you have a file called settings.xml which contains URL of the location from where you want to fetch all your dependencies like here JAR files in your case from GIT. It works from your eclipse because maven looks for dependencies in your .m2 folder which are there when you run it from eclipse. But, in order to build it from anywhere else you need to specify that URL in maven's settings.xml

Comment: Thanks Arun for the response. I will try and let you know . Meanwhile I am getting the following errors in Jenkins during Maven compilation [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_Automation/src/businesscomponents/page1.java:[873,47] cannot find symbol  symbol:   method get_testcase_id()
  location: variable threadutils_sb of type support_libraries.ThreadUtils
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Automation/src/businesscomponents/page2.java:[877,47] cannot find symbol  symbol:   method get_tc_name()
  location: variable threadutils_sb of type support_libraries.ThreadUtils

Comment: Any idea how to resolve this issue. I have tried various solutions provided in Stack Overflow and none of them worked

Comment: It means dependency of project that contains **get_testcase_id()** and **get_tc_name()** are missing from your current project's dependencies in pom.xml. Add these and this error will go

Comment: Thank you .I uploaded the entire framework source code instead of converting to a jar which resolved the issue . I am able to run the test cases in Jenkins now but I am not able to view my html report which i generate during the test execution .I use Extent Reports to generate html reports.

Comment: It is no longer related to your maven compile issue. Please raise a different question for html reports with jenkins. Also, accept the answer if it solved your original issue.